# Mixing DBM Rewrite and Redirect how to stop Rewrite if url is not in list

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, mod-rewrite

The scenario: I need to be able to both redirect certain urls and rewrite other URL's

Right now after much tinkering I am able to get almost everything to work

If I hit the `example.com` works normally and 200

If I hit the `example.com/testrea` the text from `example.com/test11/ucm25685.htm` is displayed and 200

If I hit `example.com/retest111/totest11.htm` the redirect to `example.com/test1/ucm12347.htm` does happen however I get a 403 Forbidden

How do I stop the 403 Forbidden? I think I know why it is happening however cannot figure out how to stop it. If I disable the rewrite part the redirect works find and does not display the 403 forbidden.

Why is the 403 Forbidden happening, as can be seen by the logs, when a page is requested and not in the RewriteMap examplemap (rewrite.dbm) It will send `/`. Which I though would be a missing index, however adding `-Indexes` to the `Options` made no change, and `/` does have an index.htm which is defined in the vhost.

The question is when a request is made how can I not rewrite if the url is not in the RewriteMap examplemap (rewrite.dbm) file?

Or is there a better way to Mix Rewrites and Redirects keeping in mind this is only for POC in production I will have a couple hundred Rewrites or Redirects and the dbm files will be updated as new pages are moved.

Log output LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

example.com

```
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] rewrite '/' -> '/index.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] local path result: /index.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] prefixed with document_root to /var/www/sites/me/index.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56079] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f697290/initial] go-ahead with /var/www/sites/me/index.htm [OK]
```

example.com/testrea

```
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /testrea
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/testrea'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/testrea'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] rewrite '/testrea' -> '/test11/ucm25685.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] local path result: /test11/ucm25685.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] prefixed with document_root to /var/www/sites/me/test11/ucm25685.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10407] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56111] 55.66.77.88 - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f698700/initial] go-ahead with /var/www/sites/me/test11/ucm25685.htm [OK]
```

example.com/retest111/totest11.htm

```
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /retest111/totest11.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/retest111/totest11.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] rewrite '/retest111/totest11.htm' -> '/test1/ucm12347.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] explicitly forcing redirect with http://example.com/test1/ucm12347.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] escaping http://example.com/test1/ucm12347.htm for redirect
[DATE] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f69f2d0/initial] redirect to http://example.com/test1/ucm12347.htm [REDIRECT/301]
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /test1/ucm12347.htm
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/test1/ucm12347.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/test1/ucm12347.htm'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] rewrite '/test1/ucm12347.htm' -> '/'
[DATE] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] local path result: /
[DATE] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 10412] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 55.66.77.88:56126] 55.66.77.88  - - [example.com/sid#55ac8f2ead48][rid#55ac8f691260/initial] go-ahead with / [OK]
```

Current Layout of Webroot

```
test1/ucm12347.htm
test2/ucm23452.htm
test3/ucm34674.htm
test4/ucm43489.htm
test5/ucm10963.htm

test11/ucm25685.htm
test22/ucm87546.htm
test33/ucm32548.htm
test44/ucm95142.htm
test55/ucm56485.htm

/retest111/totest11.htm
/retest222/totest22.htm
/retest333/totest33.htm
/retest444/totest44.htm
/retest555/totest55.htm
```

2 Text files that are being converted to DB and DBM files:

rewrite.txt

```
httxt2dbm -i rewrite.txt -o rewrite.dbm

/ index.htm
/testrea test11/ucm25685.htm
/testreb test22/ucm87546.htm
/testrec test33/ucm32548.htm
/testred test44/ucm95142.htm
/testree test55/ucm56485.htm
```

redirects.txt

```
httxt2dbm -f db -i redirects.txt -o redirects.db

/retest111/totest11.htm test1/ucm12347.htm
/retest222/totest22.htm test2/ucm23452.htm
/retest333/totest33.htm test3/ucm34674.htm
/retest444/totest44.htm test4/ucm43489.htm
/retest555/totest55.htm test5/ucm10963.htm
```

In the httpd.conf I have a global rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/rewrite.dbm"
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /${examplemap:$1}
</IfModule>
```

And a separate Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/me
    ServerName example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.htm
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteMap redirects dbm=db:/etc/httpd/conf/redirects.db
    RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "I think I know why it is happening" - What do you think is triggering the 403?

Comment: @MrWhite I updated the question:  Why is the 403 Forbidden happening, as can be seen by the logs, when a page is requested and not in the RewriteMap examplemap (rewrite.dbm) It will send /. Which I though would be a missing index, however adding -Indexes to the Options made no change, and / does have an index.htm which is defined in the vhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 403 is triggered because your `DirectoryIndex` document (ie. `index.htm`) does not exist. However, that is just the end result of the real underlying problem... you are *unconditionally* rewriting to the return value of your **examplemap** `RewriteMap` (which could be "empty"). I suspect you'll see the same result if you requested `example.com/test1/ucm12347.htm` directly or any URL that does not exist in your **examplemap** `RewriteMap`.

When the lookup is not found in your **examplemap** `RewriteMap` (which is looked up on every request that doesn't *redirect*) then you end up rewriting to `/` (the document root) because the result returned from your rewrite map is empty. This will trigger mod_dir to serve the `DirectoryIndex`. If the `DirectoryIndex` document does not exist and the `Indexes` *option* is not enabled then you'll get a 403 Forbidden.

You solved this problem with your **redirects** `RewriteMap` by creating a *condition* that first checks the return value from the `RewriteMap`. You'll need to do something similar with your **examplemap** `RewriteMap`. For example:

```
RewriteMap examplemap "dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/rewrite.dbm"
RewriteCond ${examplemap:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*) /${examplemap:$1} [L]
```

---

*Alternative:*

> ```
> RewriteCond ${redirects:$1} !=""
> RewriteRule ^(.*) /${redirects:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
> ```

You could store the result of the `RewriteMap` lookup in an environment variable, to avoid multiple lookups (in the *condition* and `RewriteRule` *substitution*). Although the results of the `RewriteMap` lookup are cached, so this may not see any benefit. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=REDIRECT_TO:${redirects:$1}]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_TO} .
RewriteRule ^ /%{ENV:REDIRECT_TO} [redirect=permanent,last]
```

Comment: MrWhite I believe the same that not matter what url is called the RewriteMap for the rewrites is being searched, I have also moved the rewrites to the global and the directs to inside the vhost hoping I could reverse the order. I did however add index.htm to the test1 directory which made no change, the rewrite is working in the browser address bar however the logs point to / and / does have index.htm. so how do I stop the rewrite If the path is not listed in the rewritemap?